# How do I wait for a user response when using UIAlertView?

Tags: objective-c, modal-dialog, uialertview, objective-c-blocks, wait

I'm having a lot of trouble trying to get my Objective-C code to wait appropriately for user input from a UIAlertView before triggering subsequent code. For example, I have the following code:

```
if (!self.currentUser) [self displayLoginUIAlertView];
Program *program = [[Program alloc] initWithUser:self.currentUser];
[program startProgram];
```

Where `Program` is a custom object and where user input from `[self displayLoginUIAlertView]` sets the property `self.currentUser`.

I would prefer *not* to put the second and third lines (`Program *program` and `[program startProgram]` into `alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex` as I am trying to limit the number of different types of alert views in my view controller. Additionally, I would prefer not to create my own custom fully-modal UIAlertView object (as some solutions online have seemed to suggest).

The answer I am looking for will hopefully be generalizable beyond UIAlertView objects and will help answer the more general question of how to wait for a line in Objective-C to execute fully before moving onto the next lines of code. I have also tried the following:

```
if (!self.currentUser) [self displayLoginUIAlertView];
while (!self.currentUser) wait(1);
Program *program = [[Program alloc] initWithUser:self.currentUser];
[program startProgram];
```

However, this (unsurprisingly) leads to an infinite loop wherein the alert view never appears and user input is locked out.

I have looked into using blocks but am super-confused by their syntax. Are blocks the solution? Or am I asking the wrong question?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "I am trying to limit the number of different types of alert views in my controller"? I don't see what the issue is in putting this code in the delegate callback.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The proper way is indeed to implement `alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex:` at al.

However, you might want to create an object that can take a callback block and act as a delegate for your `UIAlertView`, but I think it's more trouble than it's worth.. (you'd have to keep your delegate object in an instance variable reference to keep it from being dismissed)

Comment: One of the handiest uses I've found for associated objects is to tie a short-lived delegate's lifetime to its delegator's. E.g., `objc_setAssociatedObject(someUIActionSheet, &key, sheetDelegate, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN);` There's then no need to own the delegate locally (or via an ivar) -- the delegator can be the only owner.

Comment: OTOH--he will end up writing more lines of code than he desires in any case :)

Comment: I'm not quite clear on what Ken Haggarty is talking about anyways; either `displayLoginUIAlertView` displays a modal view, waiting for input or it doesn't. If it doesn't, then a) I don't see how it can work and b) there's no stopping the later lines anyways. If it does, then stopping the following lines isn't the problem -- there's something wrong inside `displayLoginUIAlertView`.

Comment: one more thought--you could add a category to UIAlertView to make it easy to set a retained delegate via a new property `retainedDelegate` or something like that… (Just in case `objc_setAssociatedObject()` is too ugly)

Comment: I wrap the association up in a method on the delegate: https://github.com/woolsweater/ActionSheetDelegate

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking, blocks are the answer, but only if the API supports them.  In the case of alert views, they do not.  It's fairly easy to extend them so that they support blocks though, for example [`UIAlertView-Blocks`](https://github.com/jivadevoe/UIAlertView-Blocks).

Attempts to tell the runtime to "pause until" is a non-starter - the system is not designed to be used that way, the UI will not function until you return from your method.  You won't get anywhere that way.

Answer (score 0):

apple designed this feature NOT to interrupt program flow, but rather to be displayed immediately prior to a method's completion.

use the UIAlert as an endpoint and fork execution inside the delegate that receives the alert's button tap.

when the method completes right after the call to display alert, the program will wait for user action and the delegate will assume control and program flow will recommence only after user clicks something.